# Using which to assign Dates

Tags: r

I have a time series of futures contracts values in R called `vxdata` in long form. At the date where the value moves from numeric to 'NA', I would like to create a column listing that date as the expiration date for that specific contract. I tried the following formula:

```
vxdata$expiration = vxdata$Dates[which(vxdata$value==NA & lag(vxdata$value)>0]
```

I receive the following error:

> Error in '$<-.data.frame'('*tmp*', "expiration", value = numeric(0)) :
>      replacement has 0 rows, data has 452200

Any suggestions on a better/correct way to execute this?

Comment: Try vxdata$Dates[which(vxdata$value==NA) & which(lag(vxdata$value)>0)]

Comment: Arrrgh. Nothing is ever "==" to NA. Learn to use `is.na`

Answer (score 0):

Use is.na() instead of ==. Here is quick demo.

```
mydate <- as.Date(c('20110101','20110201','20110301',NA,NA,'NA','20110107'),format="%Y%m%d")
expiration <- is.na(mydate)&!is.na(as.Date(c(NA, head(mydate,-1))))
(result <- data.frame(mydate,expiration))
```

Comment: I have trouble using lag function, never use that before and long time no use R...lag seems only work for timerseris data?